# No funciona mi aplicación de angular luego de usar ng build, error de CORS

Tags: angular, cors

Acabo de usar ng build en una aplicación angular de prueba que tengo y justo después de abrir el index.html la pagina estaba totalmente vacía y recibí 3 errores de este tipo:

```
Access to script at 'file:///F:/main.03457321315a1828.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Estos estaban acompañados de este otro tipo de errores:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Intente con una extensión de chrome que se supone que soluciona este problema pero aun así no funciono.

Tengo que hacer algo relacionado con CORS antes de usar ng build?

Comment: `file:///F:/` indica que se intentó abrir sin servidor web ( `http(s)://` ) el `origin` es null debido a eso mismo: abrir el html directamente desde el sistema de archivos ( `file://` ) en el navegador. si no hay `origin` no se puede evaluar el [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)  ( la O es de `origin` ). proba usar un [`ng serve`](https://docs.angular.lat/cli/serve) para tener un servidor web local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, levante el proyecto con xampp y los errores de CORS desaparecieron, pero seguía sin encontrar los módulos js. Esto sucedía porque el index html estaba buscando los módulos en localhost:// pero yo tenia los módulos en localhost://angular-13/. Solo tuve que sacar todos los archivos y ponerlos en la ruta anterior y ya la aplicación esta funcionando sin problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Estas intentando acceder a un archivo local en F:// desde un servidor, no podra acceder nunca.

Si es un archivo que estará en un server que no es el tuyo accede desde HTTP.

Si es un archivo en la misma carpeta de tu programa, revisa la ruta pero no pongas una ruta absoluta usando las unidades de disco (F:) sino que usa direccionres relativas tipo *'../assets/mi_archivo.js'*